# HTML Background Image Map

Tags: html, image, dictionary

Is it possible to create an image map from a background image? I'd like to have the sides of the screen clickable and I do not see any way to accomplish this without a map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create an absolute positioned image with the following css, so that it scales to fit the page.

```
img.bg{
     position:absolute;
     z-index:-100;
     top:0;left:0;bottom:0;right:0;
}
```

and then use this lib to ensure the image map scales with the page.

**https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/image-map-resizer**

Answer (score 6):

You may want to use transparent fixed floating `<a>` anchor tags like these:

```
<a style="display: scroll; position: fixed; top: 25px; left: 0px; width: 20px; height: 20px;" href="#"></a>

<a style="display: scroll; position: fixed; top: 25px; right: 0px; width: 20px; height: 20px;" href="#"></a>
```

You may want to use the `bottom` attribute instead of `top` to position the tags relative to the bottom of the window.